# Selecting a part of a text with apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, bigdata

I have a lot of small text files that I need to parse with regex, but I'm interested in only a part of the text (the delimiters are Section 1 .... Section n). It means that I need to isolate the part of the text and after that I can do the parsing.

I wonder if I can isolate a part of text with Pig ? I was thinking to create my own UDF but before starting this adventure, I'm coming here to ask some advice.

Comment: does your inputs are formatted or unformatted ?

Comment: The files are unstructured and formatted in txt file. I also was thinking the opposite :  search for a pattern and if this is included in the section part then I consider that the pattern is a good one.

Comment: Please have a look at piggybank they have covere 90% of the cases in terms of UDF